# cuml DBSCAN running slow with numba device array

Tags: gpu, cluster-analysis, dbscan, rapids

I'm trying to use the cuml ofrapids to accelerate the process of dbscan clustering 15millions float64 data point.

'''
pp = nb.cuda.to_device(ps) # ps is a (15636915,2) cupy array

with cuml.using_output_type('input'):
db_gpu = cumlDBSCAN(eps=0.8, min_samples=100,verbose=5).fit_predict(ps,out_dtype='int64')
'''

But it is running much slower than ski-learn which is running on cpu. And it is not taking up the full memory of my gpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYwD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGFkj.png)

Comment: [[-230.19247437   43.1092453 ]
 [-225.90078735   41.32767487]
 [-222.15249634   33.68173981]
 ...   the data looks like this

Answer (score 0):

Hu.Xuechun, just crossposting here to let you know that I've responded directly on your Github issue: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/4276.